# Composer package conflict when updating guzzlehttp

Tags: laravel, composer-php

laravel version is **5.8**, When I write this command in cmd,

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

I get the below problems:

```
Using version ^7.5 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.5, found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 7.5.0, 7.5.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires netflie/whatsapp-cloud-api ^1.3 -> satisfiable by netflie/whatsapp-cloud-api[1.3.0].
    - netflie/whatsapp-cloud-api 1.3.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-master, 7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.5.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v1.1.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.5).
    - nexmo/laravel 1.1.2 requires nexmo/client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.9.1].
    - nexmo/client 1.9.1 requires php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v1.1.1].
    - nexmo/laravel is locked to version 1.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

It's troublesome, and it seems like a **catch22** situation and I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Did you try as suggested by composer?

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle --with-all-dependencies`

This will try to figure out upgrades/downgrades of packages to fit the needs.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen yes i tried, it gives me another set of problems

Comment: Some packages use Guzzle v6, others use Guzzle v7, and you can soley install a **single** version. Either update those packages that still use v6, or downgrade the others

Comment: For example, `nexmo/client 1.9.1` is horribly outdated, it was released nearly three years ago